# ESP-32 CAM returning pictures with a grey band on them when higher resolution than VGA

Tags: file-upload, arduino, camera, base64, esp32

I am using ESP-32CAM (with an OV2640 camera) to send pictures to Google Drive, via HTTPS POST request to Google App Script. The payload photo is base64 format. The photo is uploaded and fully visible.
But at a higher resolution ( than VGA),the pictures are incomplete, they have a large part of them as a single color band. In Google Drive that band is grey, but when I download the photo, the color of the band is changed.
I checked if the buffer is too small using the psramFound() function, but that returned 1.

Photo upload on Google Drive : https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJwBq.jpg

Any idea how I can upload the photos correctly at the maximum resolution allowed by the board (UXGA-1600 x 1200)?

Thanks for help! :D

**Code that I am using under Arduino IDE (1.8.13):**

```cpp
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClientSecure.h>
#include "soc/soc.h"
#include "soc/rtc_cntl_reg.h"
#include "Base64.h"

#include "esp_camera.h"

const char* ssid     = "***";   //your network SSID
const char* password = "***";   //your network password
const char* myDomain = "script.google.com";
String myScript = "/macros/s/********/exec";    //Replace with your own url
String myFilename = "filename=ESP32-CAM.jpg";
String mimeType = "&mimetype=image/jpeg";
String myImage = "&data=";

int waitingTime = 30000; //Wait 30 seconds to google response.

#define PWDN_GPIO_NUM     32
#define RESET_GPIO_NUM    -1
#define XCLK_GPIO_NUM      0
#define SIOD_GPIO_NUM     26
#define SIOC_GPIO_NUM     27

#define Y9_GPIO_NUM       35
#define Y8_GPIO_NUM       34
#define Y7_GPIO_NUM       39
#define Y6_GPIO_NUM       36
#define Y5_GPIO_NUM       21
#define Y4_GPIO_NUM       19
#define Y3_GPIO_NUM       18
#define Y2_GPIO_NUM        5
#define VSYNC_GPIO_NUM    25
#define HREF_GPIO_NUM     23
#define PCLK_GPIO_NUM     22

void setup()
{
  WRITE_PERI_REG(RTC_CNTL_BROWN_OUT_REG, 0);
  
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(10);
  
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);

  Serial.println("");
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);  

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.print(".");
    delay(500);
  }

  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("STAIP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
    
  Serial.println("");

  camera_config_t config;
  config.ledc_channel = LEDC_CHANNEL_0;
  config.ledc_timer = LEDC_TIMER_0;
  config.pin_d0 = Y2_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d1 = Y3_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d2 = Y4_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d3 = Y5_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d4 = Y6_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d5 = Y7_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d6 = Y8_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d7 = Y9_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_xclk = XCLK_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_pclk = PCLK_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_vsync = VSYNC_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_href = HREF_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_sscb_sda = SIOD_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_sscb_scl = SIOC_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_pwdn = PWDN_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_reset = RESET_GPIO_NUM;
  config.xclk_freq_hz = 20000000;
  config.pixel_format = PIXFORMAT_JPEG;
  

  if(psramFound()){
    config.frame_size = FRAMESIZE_UXGA; // FRAMESIZE_ + QVGA|CIF|VGA|SVGA|XGA|SXGA|UXGA
    config.jpeg_quality = 10; //10-63 lower number means higher quality
    config.fb_count = 2;
  } else {
    config.frame_size = FRAMESIZE_SVGA;
    config.jpeg_quality = 12;
    config.fb_count = 1;
  }

  
  
  esp_err_t err = esp_camera_init(&config);
  if (err != ESP_OK) {
    Serial.printf("Camera init failed with error 0x%x", err);
    delay(1000);
    ESP.restart();
  }
  sensor_t * s = esp_camera_sensor_get();
  s->set_brightness(s, 0);     // -2 to 2
  s->set_contrast(s, 0);       // -2 to 2
  s->set_saturation(s, 0);     // -2 to 2
  s->set_special_effect(s, 0); // 0 to 6 (0 - No Effect, 1 - Negative, 2 - Grayscale, 3 - Red Tint, 4 - Green Tint, 5 - Blue Tint, 6 - Sepia)
  s->set_whitebal(s, 1);       // 0 = disable , 1 = enable
  s->set_awb_gain(s, 1);       // 0 = disable , 1 = enable
  s->set_wb_mode(s, 0);        // 0 to 4 - if awb_gain enabled (0 - Auto, 1 - Sunny, 2 - Cloudy, 3 - Office, 4 - Home)
  s->set_exposure_ctrl(s, 1);  // 0 = disable , 1 = enable
  s->set_aec2(s, 0);           // 0 = disable , 1 = enable
  s->set_ae_level(s, 0);       // -2 to 2
  s->set_aec_value(s, 300);    // 0 to 1200
  s->set_gain_ctrl(s, 1);      // 0 = disable , 1 = enable
  s->set_agc_gain(s, 0);       // 0 to 30
  s->set_gainceiling(s, (gainceiling_t)0);  // 0 to 6
  s->set_bpc(s, 0);            // 0 = disable , 1 = enable
  s->set_wpc(s, 1);            // 0 = disable , 1 = enable
  s->set_raw_gma(s, 1);        // 0 = disable , 1 = enable
  s->set_lenc(s, 1);           // 0 = disable , 1 = enable
  s->set_hmirror(s, 0);        // 0 = disable , 1 = enable
  s->set_vflip(s, 0);          // 0 = disable , 1 = enable
  s->set_dcw(s, 1);            // 0 = disable , 1 = enable
  s->set_colorbar(s, 0);       // 0 = disable , 1 = enable
  s->set_framesize(s, FRAMESIZE_UXGA);
}

boolean enviar = true;

void loop() {
  //if(enviar) {
    saveCapturedImage();
    enviar = false;
    delay(60000);
  //}
}

void saveCapturedImage() {
  Serial.println("Connect to " + String(myDomain));
  WiFiClientSecure client;
  
  if (client.connect(myDomain, 443)) {
    Serial.println("Connection successful");
    
    camera_fb_t * fb = NULL;
    fb = esp_camera_fb_get();  
    if(!fb) {
      Serial.println("Camera capture failed");
      delay(1000);
      ESP.restart();
      return;
    }
  
    char *input = (char *)fb->buf;
    char output[base64_enc_len(3)];
    String imageFile = "";
    for (int i=0;i<fb->len;i++) {
      base64_encode(output, (input++), 3);
      if (i%3==0) imageFile += urlencode(String(output));
    }
    String Data = myFilename+mimeType+myImage;
    
    esp_camera_fb_return(fb);
    
    Serial.println("Send a captured image to Google Drive.");
    
    client.println("POST " + myScript + " HTTP/1.1");
    client.println("Host: " + String(myDomain));
    client.println("Content-Length: " + String(Data.length()+imageFile.length()));
    client.println("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    client.println();
    
    client.print(Data);
    int Index;
    for (Index = 0; Index < imageFile.length(); Index = Index+1000) {
      client.print(imageFile.substring(Index, Index+1000));
    }
    
    Serial.println("Waiting for response.");
    long int StartTime=millis();
    while (!client.available()) {
      Serial.print(".");
      delay(100);
      if ((StartTime+waitingTime) < millis()) {
        Serial.println();
        Serial.println("No response.");
        //If you have no response, maybe need a greater value of waitingTime
        break;
      }
    }
    Serial.println();   
    while (client.available()) {
      Serial.print(char(client.read()));
    }  
  } else {         
    Serial.println("Connected to " + String(myDomain) + " failed.");
  }
  client.stop();
}

//https://github.com/zenmanenergy/ESP8266-Arduino-Examples/
String urlencode(String str)
{
    String encodedString="";
    char c;
    char code0;
    char code1;
    char code2;
    for (int i =0; i < str.length(); i++){
      c=str.charAt(i);
      if (c == ' '){
        encodedString+= '+';
      } else if (isalnum(c)){
        encodedString+=c;
      } else{
        code1=(c & 0xf)+'0';
        if ((c & 0xf) >9){
            code1=(c & 0xf) - 10 + 'A';
        }
        c=(c>>4)&0xf;
        code0=c+'0';
        if (c > 9){
            code0=c - 10 + 'A';
        }
        code2='\0';
        encodedString+='%';
        encodedString+=code0;
        encodedString+=code1;
        //encodedString+=code2;
      }
      yield();
    }
    return encodedString;
}
```